# Groff "Page n of m" with mom

Tags: groff

We're using `groff` with the `mom` macros for generating reports, and we'd like to change the page numbering from the "- n -" format to "Page n of m". Looking through the `mom` documentation, I see several ways of formatting the page number, but nothing about including the total number of pages. Is it possible to override the `mom` page numbering and include the total page count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to do this as a multi-pass operation:  first count the number of pages, then add the page count into the source.

You could get the page count from the `\n[%]` register after the whole document has been formatted (presuming you never adjusted the page count manually), so something like this (in a shell script) will get you the page count:

```
PAGE_COUNT=$(echo ".tm \n[%]" | groff -i -z -mom my_doc.mom 2>&1)
```

Then on the next pass, set that count in a register, i.e.,

```
groff -rpages=$PAGE_COUNT -mom my_doc.mom
```

and use mom's macros for setting the title.  I'm not familiar with mom specifically, but it should be similar to the generic

```
.tl ''Page % of \n[pages]''
```

Comment: That worked. I needed to set the footer, so here's what I ended up with using the mom macros: `.FOOTER_RIGHT "Page \*[PAGE#] of \n[pages]"`